# how to hide the seek bar when the Media player is not playing?

Tags: android, media-player, seekbar

I am developing a Media Player and i want to display seek bar only when the song is being played and when the song is not played or is paused i want to hide the seek bar,please help in achieving this.
i am developing android app on a htc wild fire which has android froyo 2.2 running in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Call on the seek bar should do the trick.  Subsequently, to make it reappear during other operations call:

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use somthing like that :

```
  if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false)
    {
       seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```